# Batch string variables with variables in the string name

Tags: string, batch-file

I have a batch file where I have a variable named t%num% and num is an integer and t%num%=#.
I need to set another variable called q equal to the contents of t%num%.
I tried   set q=t%num% so that q would contain a #, but it did not work.

Comment: If you can show the code, it would be easier to debug....

Comment: The concept you are using is called _array_. See [Arrays, linked lists and other structures in Batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET num=5
SET t%num%=36
CALL SET q=%%t%num%%%
ECHO %q% %t5%

GOTO :EOF
```

Uses the idea that `%` escapes `%` so that the parser substitutes-in the value of `num` and the result is `set q=%t5%`

Comment: it works, and I understand how the percent signs work, but what's the difference between set and call set?

Comment: `set` assigns the value of `%%` `t` `%num%` `%%` so will assign the literal value `%t5%`. `call set` evaluates the result hence the *contents* of `t5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can (ab)use [delayed environment variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for this purpose.

Let's say you have an environment variable **t5** defined. The following batch script will assign the content of **t5** to the variable **q**:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo t5: %t5%
set num=5
set q=!t%num%!
echo q: %q%
```

However, be aware that enabling delayed environment variable expansion will make `!` a special character not only in the batch script, but also inside the content of environment variables. Try setting the following content for *t5* before executing the little script above:

```
set t5=Hello World!
```

You will notice that the exclamation mark at the end of "Hello World" simply disappears.

Or try this cheeky bit:

```
set t5=Guess what: !num!
```

Setting *t5* like this and then executing the script, well... i leave it to you to find out what will happen :)